# Centralizar loading na página

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Estou montando um load e estou tendo 2 problemas.

1º Como deixar a div `circle` que contem a animação no centro vertical e horizontal da tela.

2º Como deixar as pontas do load arredondadas.

```css
.loading {
    background: #000;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1000;
}
.circle {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: solid 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  border-top-color: #FFF;
  animation: spin 1s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes bouncy {
  40% {
    height: 40px;
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate(0, 65px);
    height: 34px;
    border-radius: 20px;
  }
  65% {
    height: 40px; 
  }
}

@keyframes push {
  50% {
    margin-left: 56px;
  }
}

@keyframes slide {
  50% {
    margin-top: 25px;
  }
}

@keyframes pulse { 
  50% { 
    border-width: 30px;
  } 
}

@keyframes spin { 
  100% { 
    transform: rotate(360deg); 
  } 
} 

@keyframes cross {
  50% {
    margin-left: 60px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Loading -->
        <div class="loading">
            <div class="circle"></div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Olá, para centralizar um elemento vertical e horizontalmente dentro de outro, deve-se colocar esses estilos:

```
.circle{
  left:50%;
  top:50%;
  position: relative;
  margin-left:-40px; /* -1/2 width */
  margin-top:-40px; /* -1/2 height */
}
```

Essa solução é compatível com todos os browsers, antigos e modernos. A margem à esquerda deve ser -(metade da largura do elemento), e a margem no topo deve ser -(metade da altura do elemento).

Coloquei seu código nesse fiddle para exemplo, com a correção

https://jsfiddle.net/tsgsda2x/