# Margin negativo é uma prática ruim?

Tags: css

Utilizar uma *margin* com valor negativo é uma prática ruim (*bad practice*)?

Exemplo:

```
margin-top: -3px;
```

Comment: Prática ruim baseado em quê?

Comment: @jbueno acredito que existem possibilidades de posicionar um elemento sem utilizar o valor negativo, pórem não sei se utilizar desse método é uma prática ruim.

Comment: Acho que o @jbueno está querendo dizer que essa coisa de "boa prática" / "má prática" é pra ser relativizada. Seguir cegamente uma "boa prática" não garante bom código, assim como nunca usar nenhuma "má prática" também não garante nada.

Comment: @vnbrs a pergunta não tem haver com [tag:estilo-de-codificação], o problema é o efeito causado pelo valor negativo e só, estilo-de-codificação se refere ao "entendimento do código" e não a execução dele.

Comment: Arthur, nenhuma das respostas falou com detalhe sobre o box-model, não tenho mais como responder, mas pra dizer, não existe isso de pratica ruim com valores negativos no CSS, um box-model pode variar e assim o efeito da margem ou espaçamento também pode variar, existem inumeros motivos para usar valores negativos, portanto não é uma pratica ruim, você usa quando necessário, se não é necessário não use. (não dá pra dar mais detalhes devido a limitação do tamanho dos comentários)

Answer (score 3):

Não, margem negativa em CSS não é uma má prática. Margem negativa é um ótimo caminho para se negar paddings em um elemento, quando algum elemento interno deve ser posicionado de tal maneira.

Também, acho que a única maneira 100% confiável, suportada por todos os browsers, de se centralizar um elemento vertical e horizontalmente em relação a um elemento pai, é se utilizando de margem negativa, como segue o exemplo:

```
.classe_css{
  left:50%;
  top:50%;
  position: relative;
  margin-left:-40px; /* -1/2 width */
  margin-top:-40px; /* -1/2 height */
}
```

Comment: Gostei em partes da sua resposta... Não ficou claro esse exemplo, poderia explicar melhor?

Comment: Claro, eu tinha usado esse código como exemplo para responder essa [pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/188650/centralizar-loading-na-p%C3%A1gina/188652#188652). Usar margem negativa é a melhor, talvez única solução compatível com todos os browsers nesse caso, e se quiser dar uma olhada ,disponibilizei [nesse](https://jsfiddle.net/tsgsda2x/) fiddle um exemplo funcional.

Comment: Entendi... acho importante vc atualizar a resposta informando que se aplica a esse cenário. Vlw

Comment: Na real, tem uma outra forma que acho melhor ainda porque pode se aplicar mesmo que você não conheça os tamanhos das divs. Odeio margens negativas (opinião própria). Substitua as margens negativas por essa linha: `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);`

Answer (score 0):

*Margin* negativa não é necessariamente uma pratica ruim, por exemplo você consegue utilizar a técnica de *faux-columns* sem imagens.

> Negative values for margin properties are allowed, but there may be implementation-specific limits.

— W3C, sobre [margin properties](http://www.brainbell.com/tutorials/HTML_and_CSS/Using_Negative_Margins.htm)

Esse trecho foi retirado de uma discussão no iMasters sobre o mesmo assunto.

Dá uma lida neste  [artigo aqui](http://www.brainbell.com/tutorials/HTML_and_CSS/Using_Negative_Margins.htm), ele explica formas de utilizar margens negativas, mostrando formas comuns e erros também.

Comment: Concordo que não seja uma prática ruim. Eu só não colocaria referências tão antigas se tratando de CSS.

Comment: sim sim é só como exemplo existe muitos artigos muito bons para referenciar

atualizei os links e coloquei um mais recente