# Centralizar uma td de acordo com o tamanho do width

Tags: css, html5, table

Bom dia... estou criando um e-mail marketing e ele está responsivo, ou seja as `td` estão com `float left` e quando diminuindo o tamanho dela ele vai caindo um embaixo do outro. O meu problema é... quando chego em um tamanho de tela o meu conteúdo dentro da `td` ficam no canto esquerdo... e queria que ele ficasse no meio, a imagem abaixo vocês conseguem entender melhor

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O conteúdo tinha que ficar no meio... e quando fosse tela de desktop ele não pode ficar centralizado.
Detalhe: já tentei `margin: auto` e `margin: 0 auto` não deu certo, ja tentei `text-align: center` também não deu certo e não sei o que falta... Se alguém conseguir me ajudar ficaria grato.

Código abaixo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <style>
  /* bugfix iOS: remove o background da imagem depois que carregou, pra evitar bugs de renderizacao */
  img[src^="http"] {
    background: transparent;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#ffffff" topmargin="0" leftmargin="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" style="-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; font-size: 14px; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; background-color: #ffffff; font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif; text-align: center; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; width: 100% !important;">
  <center style="-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; background-color: #ffffff; font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; width: 100%;">
    <div id="principal" style="max-width: 600px; -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; text-align: left; width: 94%;" align="left">
      <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="100%" style="max-width: 600px;">
        <thead>
          <tr id="logo" height="90">
            <td bgcolor="#000" width="1%"></td>
            <td bgcolor="#000" valign="middle" align="left">
              <a href="#" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;">
                <img src="topo.png" alt="Herois de Fibra" width="100%" height="auto" border="0" style="color: #ffffff; font-size: 32px;"></a>
              </td>
              <td bgcolor="#000" width="1%"></td>
            </tr>
          </thead>

          <tr><td height="18" bgcolor="#ffffff" colspan="3"></td></tr>

          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td bgcolor="#fff" width="3%"></td>
              <td bgcolor="#fff">
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" bgcolor="#fff" width="100%">
                  <tr>
                    <td style="border-color: #fff; border-width: 10px 10px 20px; border-style: solid; text-align: left; -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;" align="left">
                      <img src="homem.png" alt="Olhar do povo, olhar da PM" width="100%" height="auto" border="0" style="color: #ffffff; font-size: 32px;">
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="conteudo" align="left" style="color: #000; font-size: 14px; border-color: #fff; border-width: 10px 10px 20px; border-style: solid;">
                      Uma nova edição do boletim <a href="#" style="color: #000;"><b>Heróis de Fibra</b></a> chega com a história do capitão Ricardo Nicotari-olhar do povo, olhar da PM. Juntos
                      com sua equipe ele desenvolveu um projeto premiado pelo Instituto Sou da Paz de policiamento comunitário na Zona Oeste de São Paulo.
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr><td height="30" bgcolor="#ffffff" colspan="3"></td></tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="conteudo" align="center">
                      <a href="#" style="color: #000; font-size: 12px;">Veja a história completa aqui</a>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
              <td bgcolor="#fff" width="3%"></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
          <tr><td height="18" bgcolor="#ffffff" colspan="3"></td></tr>
        </tr>


        <tr><td height="18" bgcolor="#ffffff" colspan="3"></td></tr>
        <tbody>
          <tr id="depoimentos">
            <td bgcolor="#fff" width="3%"></td>
            <td bgcolor="#fff">
              <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" bgcolor="#fff" width="100%" class="noticia">
                <tr>
                  <td class="titulo" style="border-color: #fff; width: 275px; border-style: solid; font-family: Tahoma,Verdana,sans-serif; font-size: 14px; text-align: left; -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; float: left" align="center">
                    <img src="colun1.png" alt="Herois de Fibra" width="100%" height="auto" border="0" style="color: #ffffff; font-size: 32px;">
                    <br>
                    Nessa edição do boletim temos também a história do cabo Clodoaldo da Silva Neves - por um fio. Um exemplo de controle
                    emocional e precisão no salvemnto, por telefone, de um bebê de dois meses em situação de risco.
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <a href="#" style="color: #000;"><b>Veja história completa aqui</b></a>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                  </td>
                  <td class="titulo" style="border-color: #fff; width: 275px; border-style: solid; font-family: Tahoma,Verdana,sans-serif; font-size: 14px; text-align: left; -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; float: left" align="center">
                    <img src="colun2.png" alt="Herois de Fibra" width="100%" height="auto" border="0" style="color: #ffffff; font-size:32px;" />
                    <br>
                    Saber exatamente a composição e a melhor forma de usar o seu colete garante mais confiança e segurança para o seu dia a dia.
                    Pensando nisso, a DuPont™ oferece workshops periódicos em seu Centro de Inovação e Tecnologia, em Paulínia.
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <a href="#" style="color: #000;"><b>Conheça mais sobre os workshops oferecidos pela DuPont™ Kevlar®</b></a>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr><td height="30" bgcolor="#ffffff" colspan="3"></td></tr>
              </table>
            </td>
            <td bgcolor="#fff" width="3%"></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>

        <tr><td height="30" bgcolor="#ffffff" colspan="3"></td></tr>
        <tbody>
          <td bgcolor="#fff" width="3%"></td>
          <td bgcolor="#fff">
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" bgcolor="#fff" width="100%" class="noticia">
              <tr>
                <td class="titulo" style="border-color: #fff; font-family: Tahoma,Verdana,sans-serif; font-size: 20px; text-align: left; -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;" align="left">
                  <img src="medalha.png" alt="Herois de Fibra" width="100%" height="auto" border="0" style="color: #ffffff; font-size: 32px;">
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td align="left" style="border-color: #fff; border-width: 10px 10px 20px; border-style: solid; font-size: 14px">
                  Está chegando a hora de condecorar os protagonistas das histórias escolhidas, os verdadeiros <a href="#" style="color: #000;"><b>Heróis de Fibra</b></a>. A Medalha Dupont™ Kevlar® será
                  construida mediante mobilização nas redes sociais, ou seja, com o compartilhamento das histórias publicadas no site. Participe!
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
          <td bgcolor="#fff" width="3%"></td>
        </tbody>

        <tr><td height="30" bgcolor="#ffffff" colspan="3"></td></tr>
        <tfoot>
          <tr bgcolor="#ffffff">
            <td colspan="3" align="center">
              <img src="footer.png" style="width: 100%; height: auto;" />
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tfoot>
      </table>
    </div>
  </center>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Olá, como eu disse [nessa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/188650/centralizar-loading-na-p%C3%A1gina/188652#188652) resposta, a maneira compatível com todos os browsers de centralizar um elemento em relação a seu pai, é colocando os seguintes estilos:

```
img{
    left: 50%;
    width: 250px; /* Largura desejada */
    position: relative;
    margin-left: -125px;   /* menos metade da largura desejada */ 
}
```

Gostaria de aproveitar para te dar umas dicas. Foi meio complicado pra eu dar manutenção no seus estilos, pois havia muita coisa inline. Recomendo que coloque os estilos repetitivos em uma classe CSS.

Arrumei seu código para centralizar as imagens, e coloquei alguns dos estilos separados no CSS, como você pode ver [aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/nv8ww4pd/) no JSFiddle.

Assim, os estilos que você alterar nas classes, replicarão em todos os elementos

Answer (score 1):

Digamos que você colocou que o tamanho do td ocupa 50% da div, por padrão, o objeto será posicionado à esquerda e no topo da div, para deixa-la centralizada, "empurre-a" 25% para a direita, assim deixando o item ocupar 50% do espaço entre 2 lados com 25%, nesse caso poderia usar tanto "padding-left", quanto "margin-left", depende da forma que quer adequar. (Esse é um dos maiores exemplos, depois de responsividade, do porque utilizar porcentagem para medidas de estilo)